# get what pivot-table timeline/slider have been selected

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am creating pivot-table and added timeline.

how to get the value of selection in the timeline. what period has been selected?

example :
https://tr2.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2013/08/22/577bcc1a-d842-496e-97ab-97e4b99c6443/resize/1200x/3284612199bd1ccd42e9c10d61f58bbd/801FigH.jpg

in this example that value I want to get is **Feb 2010**.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is really easy to do. really this is the only answer on the internet (maybe) it was hard to write the question to find the results.

https://www.excelcampus.com/pivot-tables/display-multiple-items-filter-criteria/